# Can git merge two content-addressed stores?

Tags: git

I have two git repositories. The repositories do not have any `commit` or `tag` objects, only `blob` and `tree` objects. I would like one repository which has all of the objects from both repositories.

**Can git merge two content-addressed stores?** I can write a tool that does this, but I'd like to reuse existing tools when possible.

I'd prefer to accept answers which explain what happens to any `commit` objects (easy), `tag` objects (less easy), or `branch` or `reference` pointers (hard), but I'm okay with just handling `blob` and `tree`.

Comment: Your repos have no commits or tags - your last paragraph appears to be from an earlier version of your question?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: My last paragraph is indicating priority, in case I get multiple answers. An answer which explains what happens during a merge of two typical git repositories, which carry all four types of objects and both types of pointers, is going to be accepted over an answer which only explains `blob` and `tree`.

Comment: I do not think it would be a problem if you copy the objects from one repo into the other. In case they are already packaed, unpack them to get them into the other repo (and I am not sure if doing the same with the `.pack` files would be as simple as handling the loose objects which I am inclined to think that is ok to git). Check https://git-scm.com/docs/git-unpack-objects

Comment: What is the use care for having blobs and trees that you care about without having commits?

Comment: @TTT: I'm exploring building a content-addressable store for [an esoteric programming language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cammy). There may be `commit` objects, but it is not guaranteed that every `tree` is referenced by at least one `commit`, which means that the typical `commit`-oriented merge process may miss some `tree`s.

Comment: OK. If you could somehow guarantee every valuable blob and tree is referenced by a commit, then the merge is much easier.  I don't know if this comment helps you, but perhaps achieving that guarantee might be easier than figuring out the solution as asked. ;)